# Проверка производителя на наличие товара

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть обычный цикл, выводит имя и id

> $res = mysql_query("SELECT id,name
> FROM Manufacturer WHERE Checked=1
> ORDER BY name");
>
> > ```
> > while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
> >
> > printf ("<li><a href='/manufacturer.php?id=%s'>%s</a>",$row['id'],$row['name']);
> >
> > }
> > ```

Как сделать проверку, что бы выводил те производители, где есть товары, и внутри цикла sql делал запрос на существование товаров? Уж сильно большая нагрузка на сайт получилась. Есть более эфективное решение?

Comment: А где и как у вас хранится информация о наличии товаров?

Comment: Хранится все в базе mysql, название таблиц manufacturer и tovar, поля id name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.name 
FROM Manufacturer M
   JOIN Product P ON P.manufacturer = M.id
WHERE M.Checked=1 
ORDER BY m.name
```

имена таблицы товаров и ее колонок - вымышленные

Comment: Странно, на денвере все заработало, выложил на хостинг и выдает ошибку 
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/site/public_html/mysite/blocks/manufacturer.php

Comment: sql error показывает Unknown column 'm.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Могу только посоветовать проверить, есть ли в базе на хосте реально эти таблицы и колонки. Проверить в запросе кодировку символов - может алиас М в предложении from написан русской буквой. сам запрос в виду своей примитивности ошибочным быть не может.

Comment: Ну на денвере ведь все работает)) таблицы и колонки полностью совпадают с моими, единственное Product изменил на Tovar

Comment: попробуйте поставить SELECT *
что произойдет?

Comment: На денвере заместо имен производителей, начал выводить имена товаров, а на хостинге Ошибка таже, это явно что то с алиасами, я потом поставил везде Алиас M заглавной,и цикл стал выводить много производителей с одинаковым названием, но уже без ошибок на хостинге  

Спасибо помогло, только при этом пришлось поставить алиасы заглавной буквой=)

Comment: Обновил ответ - поставьте еще фразу DISTINCT